# How to set up WSO2 API gateway?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

Good day

I have created my ESB project using the enterprise integration studio provided by wso2 and have also downloaded the API manager separately. Meanwhile when I start WSO2 API manager, API Publisher and developer dashboard open.

I just want to create WSO2 API Gateway. How can I achieve this also I want gateway should be access based.
Please assist me how can I proceed for the gateway implementation.

I only want the WSO2 API gateway.

Comment: Hi @Sajitha Liyanage  can you please assist me here ?

Comment: Did you follow the API Manager quick start guide? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/quick-start-guide/

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 APIM is consist of 5 profiles as Gateway, Traffic Manager, Publisher, Store(Devportal in APIM 3.x series) and KM profiles. You can start an APIM with the default profile (if you started as sh wso2server.sh) and you can work with each profile. But if you want to start APIM as Gateway profile, then you need to start the server with "**-Dprofile**" mode as follows.
`sh wso2server.sh -Dprofile=gateway-worker`

You can read this document https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Product+Profiles  to aware of the profile of wso2 APIM.

And WSO2 has Micro GW product too, you can find more details about that MGW here https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+the+API+Microgateway. You can download the form here  https://wso2.com/api-management/api-microgateway/ and test.

Comment: Hi @Nadee mam, Thankyou so much for your feedback. I have tried running wso2 api manager for a specific profile for gateway but there are few challenges i am facing. Might be i need to reset again.